# Is it possible to use Open MPI in Docker with the default bridge network and host port forwarding?

Tags: docker, mpi, openmpi, horovod

I am trying to use Open MPI in Docker with containers on different hosts but connected to their respective default Docker bridge networks. There is a range of TCP ports that are mapped from the Docker host to the container.

`mpirun` allows you to specify a range of ports that it should use; however, there doesn't seem to be an option that allows you to specify whether the communication should be done strictly via addresses that port forward on to where the MPI processes actually run.

Is this achievable by passing an argument to `mpirun` or is there a hard requirement on having a common routable network interface available?